# Is there a way to format a string directly within a functions arguments instead of using a temporary string?

Tags: c, printf

I have a function that accepts a string (char array) as its argument.

```
void enterString(char * my_string);
```

When using this function, I often find myself wanting to input formatted strings. I use sprintf to do this. However, It's kind of annoying that I have to create a temporary string every time:

```
char temp_str[100];
sprintf(temp_str, "My lucky number = %d", 11);
enterString(temp_str);
```

Is there any way to directly format a string within a functions arguments so I don't have to create a temporary string every time? Something like:

```
enterString("My lucky number = %d", 11);
```

Thanks

Comment: I think you need to recode a variable argument function a la printf... yes, it's annoying. I know

Comment: `char *` is a pointer to `char` in the first place. Neither a string nor an array. C does not have a string type. And either it is not clear what your problem is, or your approach is flawed.

Comment: Perhaps `vprintf()`?

Comment: @Olaf, I'm confused by your response. It is common to refer to char arrays as 'strings' in C. And when declaring functions that accept strings (char arrays) as inputs, it's valid to declare the function to accepts a pointer to the first char.

Comment: The real issue is that C doesn't have garbage-collected memory management. If you need a string, you need to declare a variable for it, there's no way to create a temporary on the fly.

Comment: @Izzo: What is not clear about "a pointer is not an array". And a char array is not a string either. Anyway, I just pointed that out, because that's a typical beginners' mistake which show confusion by itself. Additional clarification: you cannot pass arrays to a function. Once one gets these concepts right, a lot of missunderstanding just disappears.

Comment: Please, use `const` whenever possible! That function signature screams "I am going to mutate this argument"

Comment: why do you think it's annoying. It's cleaner this way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot do this in C (unlike other languages like python which have built-in formatting for string with the `%` operator or `str.format` function).

*But* since your approach looks like you want to print a formatted message with variable arguments, you could use `vfprintf` that can accept a `va_list` argument, so you can transfer your variable arguments to your inner function.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

void enterString(const char *format,...)
{

  va_list argptr;
  va_start(argptr, format);
  vfprintf(stdout, format, argptr);
  va_end(argptr);
  // rest of the processing here
}

int main()
{
   enterString("My lucky number = %d", 11);
   return 0;
}
```

This doesn't bring a lot compared to `printf`, but now that you have this, 
you can add a check for "verbose" mode, log to a file, print a prefix, date, ... before the message, etc...

I found this exact code in the musashi 680x0 emulator (in m68kfpu.c)

```
static void fatalerror(char *format, ...) {
  va_list ap;
  va_start(ap,format);
  vfprintf(stderr,format,ap);
  va_end(ap);
  exit(1);
}
```

(I had to fix the wrong `fprintf` that was in the code, but apart from that, we see a direct application: this function is used to print a variable formatted error message, then quit to the operating system)

Comment: Why wouldn't he just call `printf()` directly instead of this function? Presumably his function needs to use the formatted string for something.

Comment: He could print some prefix first or after. He could decide not to print if a flag is set, print to stderr, log to a file a the same time... will edit