# Calling sprintf() under a variadic function in C

Tags: c, variadic-functions

I want to write a quick `printf()` kinda function for an embedded board that I am working on where the output terminal is a serial port. I tried something like this:

```
int32_t printfDebugSerial(const char *format, ...)
{
  char tempBuff[256];
  memset(tempBuff, 0, sizeof tempBuff);

  va_list arg;
  int32_t done;
  va_start (arg, format);
  done = (int32_t)sprintf(tempBuff,format, arg);
  va_end (arg);

  HAL_sendToSerial((uint8_t*)tempBuff, strlen(tempBuff)); // writes bytes to serial port
  return done;
}
```

But the output that I got when I called it as follows:

```
printfDebugSerial("Hello = %u", 1234);
```

output:

```
Hello = 536929228
```

then called as:

```
printfDebugSerial("Hello = %f", 934.3245);
```

output:

```
Hello = 0.000000
```

Any help, what is wrong here?

Comment: Use vsnprintf()

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46100864/is-there-a-way-to-format-a-string-directly-within-a-functions-arguments-instead

Comment: If you're using GCC, compile with `-Wall -Werror`.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart, it worked without '-Wall -Werror'

Comment: @HansPassant, thank you so much, just curious why sprintf() did not worked?

Comment: Forwarding the variable length argument list requires extra magic, only the vxxxprintf functions know how to do that.

Comment: @HansPassant, haha got you :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use [vsprintf](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/vfprintf) instead of sprintf if you are forwarding `va_list`'s:

```
int32_t printfDebugSerial(const char *format, ...)
{
  char tempBuff[256];
  memset(tempBuff, 0, sizeof tempBuff);

  va_list arg;
  int32_t done;
  va_start (arg, format);
  done = (int32_t)vsprintf(tempBuff,format, arg);
  va_end (arg);

  HAL_sendToSerial((uint8_t*)tempBuff, strlen(tempBuff)); // writes bytes to serial port
  return done;
}
```

Comment: thank you so much, just curious why sprintf() did not worked?

Comment: If you have a `%u` in your format, sprintf will expect an unsigned integer - but in your case the parameter type was a `va_list` instead, which doesn't work. `sprintf` usually [creates a va_list internally](https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/master/stdio-common/sprintf.c), just like you did, and calls ``vsprintf`` with it.